# Multiplication row by row

Tags: bash, awk

I know how to multiply numbers in columns but I can't cope with multiplication in rows. I would like to calculate a third power of each number in a first row, then multiply it by number from  the second row and a constant variable. There are always two lines, for example:

Input: constant: `x`

```
a c ... ...
b d ... ...
```

I would like to have an output like this:

```
(a^3)*b*x (c^3)*d*x ... ...
```

Input of some real numbers: constant: `0.30` and four columns.

```
1.00    2.00    4.00    7.00    
1.10    1.05    0.30    0.10
```

Output:

```
0.33    2.52    5.76    10.29
```

Hope someone will help. Thank you.

Comment: what are the 3rd and 4th columns supposed to be? Same `a c \ b d` structure? Also, are you always having just two lines and four columns?

Comment: There are always only 2 lines and 20 columns.

Comment: So again, what is the structure? You define it for 2x2

Comment: No. Note for asking a good question here it is good to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Do you want an ugly code? Why don't you do this in python, ruby, ... ?

Comment: I understand, but if I will get answer for 4 columns I will solve a problem for `n` columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will be more intuitive

```
$ tr -s ' ' '\n' < file | pr -2t | awk -v x=0.3 '{printf "%.2f ", $1^3*$2*x} END{print ""}'
0.33 2.52 5.76 10.29
```

transpose the data file so that related fields are on the same row, compute, transpose.

Answer (score 1):

gawk

```
awk -vx=0.3 '{for(i=0;++i<=NF;)a[NR][i]=$i}NR>1{for(i=0;++i<=NF;)printf "%s ",(a[NR-1][i]^3)*a[NR][i]*x;print ""}' file
0.33 2.52 5.76 10.29
```

Comment: This may well solve the problem, but please also provide an explanation. Many new users come to SO and explanation with your code helps them to learn how to adapt the code to solve their problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to read lists in python. Please find reference [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html). Your problems is you need to get your hands dirty with code. Start practicing more programming questions. :)

```
input_vals= [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,3,5,7,9]] # Can be of any form, I used 2-D Array
a = input_vals[0]
b = input_vals[1]
x = 0.5 # Constant Value
# Now all you need is to read value and do your operation
for i in xrange(len(a)):
    print (a[i]**3)*b[i]*x
# Or here is one liner for your question     
print [(a[i]**3)*b[i]*0.5 for i in range(len(a))]
```